# Decrypt List value in Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, encryption

I'm developing a mobile application that implements AES encryption with AESMode.cbc . The following is the class that I use for the encryption and decryption process.

```
class EncDecHelper {
  static encryp(text) {
    final phoneNumber = UserConstant.phoneNumber;
    String additionalKey = (phoneNumber.length == 11)
        ? '12345'
        : (phoneNumber.length == 12)
            ? '1234'
            : '';
    final key = Key.fromUtf8('${phoneNumber}4fJX3qWwdlFrCQAd$additionalKey');
    final iv = IV.fromUtf8('4fJX3qWwdlFrCQAd');
    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(text, iv: iv);
    print("Text $text");
    print("Encrypted Text ${encrypted.base64}");
    return encrypted.base64;
  }

  static decryp(text) {
    final phoneNumber = UserConstant.phoneNumber;
    String additionalKey = (phoneNumber.length == 11)
        ? '12345'
        : (phoneNumber.length == 12)
            ? '1234'
            : '';
    final key = Key.fromUtf8('${phoneNumber}4fJX3qWwdlFrCQAd$additionalKey');
    final iv = IV.fromUtf8('4fJX3qWwdlFrCQAd');
    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
    Encrypted enBase64 = Encrypted.from64(text);
    final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(enBase64, iv: iv);
    print("Text $text");
    print("Decrypted Text $decrypted");
    return decrypted;
  }
}
```

Here I encrypt each value that will be used for the api request and the api response that I get is data that has been encrypted from the server.

An example of the process I carried out is as follows:

A. API Request Parameters

```
phoneNumber : 0123456
```

I encrypted the value of the phoneNumber

B. Response Data API

```
status : success
data : [{name: John, age: 22, gender: male}, {name: Ana, age: 24, gender: female}]
```

*all response values are in encrypted form

The following is how I implemented that encryption and decryption.

A. Encryption of API Request Parameter Data

```
dataMap.forEach((key, value) {
       dataMap[key] = EncDecHelper.encryp(value);
       print(dataMap[value]);
     });
```

B. Decrypt API Response Data

```
responseData = json.decode(response.body);
responseData.forEach((key, value) {
         responseData[key] = EncDecHelper.decryp(value);
       });
```

When the response data is not in list form, I can decrypt the response value so I can see the original value of the response. However, I have difficulty if it is in list form. For example this one:
`data : [{name: John, age: 22, gender: male}, {name: Ana, age: 24, gender: female}]`

How can I decrypt the data if it is in list form.

I have tried and this error appears
error type
`'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`